# Return arbitrary points on a curve in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, interpolation

Suppose that I have a series of points, the x-axis coordinate values are stored in a vector `xx` and the y-axis values are stored in a vector `yy`. So I can plot the curve by `plot(xx,yy)`.

Now I have another vector `xxx`, the elements in `xxx` may not be in vector `xx`. If I use `xxx` as x-axis values, how do I get the `Y` values corresponding to `xxx`?

Comment: Use either: `interp1`, `spline`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by [RobertStettler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31530583/return-arbitrary-points-on-a-curve-in-matlab#comment51022218_31530583) you can interpolate to get the `y` values corresponding to `x` values in `xxx`. Matlab can offer several interpolation methods using [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html), for example, a linear interpolation:

```
yyy = interp1( xx, yy, xxx, 'linear' );
```

Answer (score 2):

`interp1`

Specifically,

```
yyyy = interp1(xx,yy,XXX);
```

This is a pretty full featured function, be sure to check `help interp1` to see everything that it can do.

Comment: Thanks, Pursuit. Both you and Shai provided the corrected answer, but since Shai's answer is more earlier, so I should accept Shai's as The Answer. Sorry about this.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Relatively easy questions are basically little typing races.